# ¿como pasar por parámetro, un mensaje recibido de Facebook a una función de Java?

Tags: java

Cómo se podría pasar por parámetro, un mensaje de Facebook,recibido.
Es para hacer un bot, que responda los mensajes.
Con la api de simsimi.[Código esta compilado en Eclipse](https://mega.nz/#!7RhlTLCC!hcejwdxXxI8WQDMcmY6Ew47pRNRLjSdxA5UuQ5oDWjQ)

Comment: Hola Jhon, bienvenido! En vez de poner una imagen, ¿podrías poner el código con lo que probaste hasta ahora? Para hacerlo, podrás [edit] la pregunta y, luego de agregar el código, podés hacer click en el botón `{ }` para darle formato.

Comment: Claro que sí, Mariano

Comment: Mariano mejor subi el código a mega para que lo puedas ver más en detalle.